# I only get the url index when doing ionic build

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, browser, build

I am having problems disploying the website on a web server.

For that I run the following command

```
ionic build
```

Then I copy what is in the build folder to the web server

But it only shows me the url index.html. When in index, I click a button to redirect me to a specific url, like / login, it can’t find the page.

How can I build all urls and not only the index page?

Thanks in advance

PS: I have http Requests in it...

Answer (score 1):

That is a problem of web server configuration, if you click on a button that should redirect to ex: `/about` web server searches for `about/index.html` or `about.html`, which obviously cannot be found, as `build` compiles whole app into a single index.html.

You need to edit configuration file of web server and add a rule to redirect any url to `index.html`, and thus allow ionic itself to manage url access control.

Note: If you want just a web app, i wouldn't use ionic. Your project would have a lot of stuff that is not used. Instead you could just go angular or react or whatever

Comment: jup exaclty. for e.g. nginx you would add the index.html to your location config as an additional fallback. like so: location / { try_files $uri /index.html; }

Comment: Yes, for nginx it would be `location / { try_files $uri /index.html; }` you sure you got that the right way? and it still doesnt work?